# Return a "None" row after sending data from python to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am working on my project but I am facing problem with passing data from python to MySQL
the code works fine and didn't give me an error but it insert"None" in the table!! and I don't know where the error is?

```
def report_proble():
top=Toplevel()
top.title('Report problem window')
name = Label(top, text = "Name:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300,y = 50)
email = Label(top, text = "Email:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300, y = 90) 
problem=Label(top, text = "Report your problem:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300, y = 130)
e1 = Entry(top).place(x = 340, y = 50)
e2 = Entry(top).place(x = 340, y = 90)
Text1=tk.Text(top, height=10,width=50).place(x=300,y=170)

bmitbtn = Button(top, text = "Submit",activebackground = '#3C919D', activeforeground = "blue",command=lambda:db(name,email,problem)).place(x=450,y=340)

def db(name,email,problem)
if(name=="" or email=="" or problem==""):
    MessageBox.showinfo("Insert Status","All fields are required")
else:
    mycursor.execute ("INSERT INTO problem(name,email,problem) values('%s','%s','%s')"%(name,email,problem))
    mycursor.close()
    mydb.commit()

    MessageBox.showinfo("Thank you for the feedback!")
    mydb.close()
```

and the table in MySQL is

Name, Email, Problem
'None', 'None', 'None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
name = Label(...).place(...)
email = Label(...).place(...)
problem=Label(...).place(...)
```

This is setting `name`, `email`, and `problem` all to `None`. That is because in python `x = y().z()` sets `x` to `z`. Since `.place(...)` always returns `None`, your variables are getting set to `None`.

Therefore, because of this:

```
bmitbtn = Button(..., command=lambda:db(name,email,problem))....
```

... you are always passing `None, None, None` to the function.

As a best practice, you should never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the same line that the widget is created. It's a bad habit that will result in errors like this.

If you want `name`, `email` and `problem` to be references to the widgets, you need to separate widget creation from widget layout:

```
name = Label(...)
email = Label(...)
problem=Label(...)

name.place(...)
email.place(...)
problem.place(...)
```

Now, let's look at the `db` function:

```
def db(name,email,problem)
    if(name=="" or email=="" or problem==""):
        MessageBox.showinfo("Insert Status","All fields are required")
```

The values will *never* be an empty string. At the moment they are always `None` because that's what you're passing in. However, even if `name`, `email`, and `problem` are not `None`, they will still never be an empty string since you're attempting to pass a widget reference rather than a string.

All of that being said, it makes little sense to be passing the labels to the function. The data input by the user won't be in the labels. Instead, you need to be passing in the entry and text widgets, and then calling the `.get()` method inside the function to get the data:

```
e1 = Entry(top)
e2 = Entry(top)
text1=tk.Text(top, height=10,width=50)
...
bmitbtn = Button(..., command=lambda:db(e1, e2, text1))
```

Then, define `db` to fetch the data before using the data:

```
def db(name_entry,email_entry,problem_text):
    name = name_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    problem = problem_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer that helps me a lot!! but I am getting an error with get() "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Albandry: yes, you will get that error if you don't follow my advice. That means that somewhere in your code you're doing `x.get()`, and `x` is set to None. In a tkinter program that almost always means you did `x = SomeWidget(...).place(...)` (or `.grid...` or `.pack...`), which causes `x` to be `None`.

Comment: I follow your advice and its finally works!! Thank you again I was facing this problem from 3 days and you save my life bro I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Albandry: the next time you are about to spend three days on a problem, slow down, examine your variables one by one while the program runs, and ask yourself if they are what they should be. If they are not, keep tracing back to where they are defined and then figure out why they are set to something other than what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the connection to database and im pretty sure that u can use  `values(%s,%s,%s)`
instead `values('%s','%s','%s')`.

Or one better example for you:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO problem (name, email,problem) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)"
val = ("yourdata", "yourdata", "yourdata")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Your code edited:

```
def report_proble():
top=Toplevel()
top.title('Report problem window')
name = Label(top, text = "Name:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300,y = 50)
email = Label(top, text = "Email:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300, y = 90) 
problem=Label(top, text = "Report your problem:",bg='#BFD5ED').place(x = 300, y = 130)
e1 = Entry(top).place(x = 340, y = 50)
e2 = Entry(top).place(x = 340, y = 90)
Text1=tk.Text(top, height=10,width=50).place(x=300,y=170)

bmitbtn = Button(top, text = "Submit",activebackground = '#3C919D', activeforeground = "blue",command=lambda:db(name,email,problem)).place(x=450,y=340)

def db(name,email,problem)
if(name=="" or email=="" or problem==""):
    MessageBox.showinfo("Insert Status","All fields are required")
else:
    sql = "INSERT INTO problem (name, email,problem) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)"
    val = (name, email, problem)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()

    MessageBox.showinfo("Thank you for the feedback!")
    mydb.close()
```

Update:

Change `val = (name, email, problem)` to `val = (e1, e2, text1)`
because you collect your data here not in name,email,problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I actually writhe the connection and it is working fine and I change the code but still give me no data in MySQL table! I tried many ways to insert data but still give me nothing

Comment: The quotes are required in the `values` section, unless the actual values themselves already have quotes. String substitution isn't the best way to add parameters to a query, partially for this very reason.

Comment: You take your data in e1 , e2 and text1 ?